# Как подключить библиотеку, написанную на С++, к С# по средствам COM?

Tags: c#, .net, com, c++

Можно подробно (пошагово) рассказать, как правильно создать саму библиотеку на С++, зарегистрировать ее в реестре и подключить к С# приложению?

Спасибо.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6tx9dw3.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Легче всего это сделать используя ATL.
Создание библиотеки: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38254/A-Beginner-Tutorial-for-Writing-Simple-COM-ATL-DLL
Использование:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkcominteroptutorialputtingitalltogether